# How to view the command executed in a script as it is executed?

Tags: bash

I have a bash script I've written to automate something tedious, so I got the command looking right in echo, but when I run it, it doesn't work. This is what I'm doing:

```
CMD='custom_script update --flag=value --comment="testing"'
echo -e "Running $CMD"
$CMD
```

The echo shows:
custom_script update --flag=value --comment="testing"

which is correct, but that is not what is actually run with the $CMD line (I know because if I copy and paste the output from echo, it works, but the error message after running in the script suggests the quoting is off).

I think I can figure this out if I can see the command run by $CMD, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Please see [BashFAQ/050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) and [BashFAQ/048](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048).

Answer (score 3):

Run it like

```
bash -x script.sh
```

or modify the shebang like

```
#!/bin/bash -x
```

Comment: What does that do? What I posted was a simplified version of the script, and adding -x to the shebang printed all sorts of other stuff with + and ++ in front of the code, like:
    ++ awk '{ print $2 }'

Comment: Using `-x` is quite good advice, it lets you see each line as it is executed. Here's the documentation on `-x` from the bash man page: https://gist.github.com/709592

Answer (score 0):

Looks like

```
eval $CMD
```

is what I needed.